# How to display 20 records on every page of crystal report?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and I need to print 20 rows of data per page.
I found this on the web but it is not working on my system.

```
if Remainder(Recordnumber,20)=0 then true else false
```

My system only prints a row per page.

Answer (score 1):

To make it show 10 records per page do the following

1. Open the report in Design View
2. Right click on the Details section and select Section Expert
3. Make sure the Details section is selected in the Section Expert dialog box. Check the box that says “New Page After”
4. Click the formula editor button to the right of the checkbox.
5. Enter the following formula

`if Remainder (RecordNumber, 10) = 0 then true else false`

1. Click Save and Close and then click OK.

If you run the report it should break after each 10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

To show 20 records per page do the following

1. Open the report in Design View
2. Right click on the Details section and select Section Expert
3. Make sure the Details section is selected in the Section Expert dialog box. Check the box that says “New Page After”
4. Click the formula editor button to the right of the checkbox.
5. Enter the following formula

   if Remainder (RecordNumber, 20) = 0 then true else false
6. Click Save and Close and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something pedantic as `RecordNumber` is `Recordnumber` in your code?

```
if Remainder (RecordNumber, 20) = 0 then true else false
```

Comment: I think the code works for second page.Does the above code work for the first page too.I need to display 20 record.if there is any suggestion do give me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Crystal reports 2008/2011 there is a new options in the details section properties in the section expert - 'New page after: X Visible Records':

[image: Example image]

Comment: This option is not working with me. Do you think I need to do something else regarding that?

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari Nothing special you need to do, just make sure that it's the detail lines you are displaying and not the group headers. Also iirc this only works if you use the Crystal Report viewer bundled with CR2008/11.